# html5 video player (without direct source) prevent downloading

Tags: html, html5-video, mp4

I'm developing a website where users can publish their videos (similar to youtube). Is there a way to play my videos in html5 player without direct source, like youtube doing? Are there any plugins/scripts? It would be great if you dropped a link to a plugin/script. Please help me.

Currently I'm doing like this ("uploads/movie.mp4"):

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls="controls">
  <source src="uploads/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

Comment: Direct link to what? The video file?

Comment: i mean the source (src="uploads/movie.mp4")

Comment: You cannot prevent a user downloading the movie. Not without some DRM, but even then there will be a way.

Comment: You need DRM if you want to prevent downloads. DRM can be used if you use Silverlight to play the videos. Is this acceptable in your scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"If you don’t want people to steal your stuff, don’t put it on the internet."
-Unknown user-

At the moment there s no way to prevent this via HTML5-videoelement.

to make it more difficult, you can try sth with javascript, f.e. disabling "right-click" ( http://www.webpagemistakes.ca/disable-right-click/ )